# C-preprocessor macro that would wrap text before/after token with another text

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to create C preprocessor macro that would allow me to call methods on strings(char[]).

e.g.:

```
char myStr[10];

int len = strlen(myStr);
```

Would become:

```
char myStr[10];
int len = myStr.len;
```

or:

```
char myStr[10];
int len = LEN myStr;
```

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, this question is about **C-preprocessor** not C language itself. For all intents and purposes, the code above could be replaced with JavaScript, PHP, or **even plain text**.

All I am asking is, whether is it possible to write macro that would wrap text before token or after token with some other text.

Generally speaking, the following transformation:

**token** *text* => wrap *text* wrap

or

*text* **token** => wrap *text* wrap

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why at all do you want this? Don't work against the language. -- Your first idea cannot work because an array of `char` is no `struct`, therefore the point operator is not applicable. Your second idea cannot work because C has no expressions to express this. You can define a macro to realize `int len = LEN(myStr);` but then you can call `strlen()` directly.

Comment: @thebusybee I have updated my question to make it clearer what I am asking about. I hope this helps.

Comment: Example 2 could be achieved in C++ with `std::string`. But, it's invalid C. C doesn't have "properties" like php, java*, or python/raku. Because `myStr` is a `char` array, you can't use struct "member" syntax on it (e.g. the `.` operator). You'd need something like: `struct string { int len; char str[10]; };  struct string myStr; int len = myStr.len;` This, of course, assumes that when one fills in `.str`, we also call `strlen` to set `.len`. You didn't show a [cpp] macro for what you want, so we can only speculate. You might be better off with a code generator like autoconf's use of `m4`

Comment: @CraigEstey Well, I don't really need it for C but for any language. I will look into m4 but it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, the preprocessor cannot do this:

**token** *text* => wrap *text* wrap

or

*text* **token** => wrap *text* wrap

In simple words, its replacing capabilities include only, and the **token** needs to be an identifier:

**token** => replacement

**token** '(' *argument(s)* ')' => replacement with 0 to all of _argument(s)

See the chapter 6.10.3 of the standard.

---

You might want to do some research on other macro processors, for example starting on the [respective Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_macro_processor). Please note that recommendations are off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define strlen(str) str.len

int foo(char *str)
{
    size_t x = strlen(str);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/45xY1zzhd